# What's the difference between a "bit" and "octet"?

Tags: python-3.x

What's the difference between a "bit" and "octet"? Some python books, depending on the author, seem to use the terms interchangeably. I asked a PHD level guy and he said there was a difference but didn't explain what the difference was.

Comment: A bit is a single binary digit (b[inarydig]it). An octet is a set of 8(oct) binary digits, or a byte.

Comment: On any hardware you'll ever actually see, there's no difference. In theory, you could have a machine with bytes that aren't 8 bits. None of them are in common use anywhere. The wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing) may be helpful?

Answer (score 17):

A bit is a single binary digit.

An octet is a collection 8 bits, sometimes called a "byte". There is no formal definition of a byte as 8 bits (though it is the generally accepted standard). The term octet is used when it is necessary to unambiguously specify that there are only 8 bits in the collection.

Answer (score 11):

An octet is **always** eight bits.  A byte is typically eight bits, or the width of a character in a given architecture.  Some older computers represented characters in six bits.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte .